# does clients need an organization in fabric network? what should we do when endorsing process take some time?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have some questions regarding the deployment of a HLF use case. consider that we want to implement a network for insurance industry.
clients want to interact with an insurance company to make an agreement and whenever they suffer from an accident, make a request to claim their funds.

---

We also have an organization that assesses the damage.
When the customer requests an assessment, the damage assessment process may take several days.
In the compensation process, the assessors must endorse the transaction.

---

1. Do customers in the network need an organization and peer or is it enough to be interacted with the application?
2. Doesn't the fact that transactions take several days to be endorsed pose a problem for the network? What solution do you suggest for its implementation? What functions should be used in a developing Chaincodes?
3. The documents that assessors want to record after completing their work may include images, videos, and a lot of information. How should this information be stored on the network? Doesn't it create a heavy load on the network?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Currently, your question may be subjective and asks for multiple questions. In fact, find out what `take several days to be endorsed` you want to solve, and if you fail after trying, bring the code with you so that you can reproduce it.
See the guide. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> Do customers in the network need an organization and peer or is it enough to be interacted with the application?

It's up to you whether or not you want to register your users on the blockchain. Registering and enrolling an identity in a Hyperleder Fabric network means you're making them a member of an organization. With registering identities on the blockchain, you can have better access control management of identities. Also, if you're registering a user on the blockchain, the admin would be able to see in the ledger which member did a particular transaction. You can achieve the same without registering members on blockchain but it's one of the perks and underlying principles of Hyperledger Fabric so why not leverage it.

> Doesn't the fact that transactions take several days to be endorsed pose a problem for the network? What solution do you suggest for its implementation? What functions should be used in a developing Chaincodes?

No, transactions don't take several days to get endorsed in Hyperleder Fabric. It takes only a few seconds to complete a transaction. And, you can increase the throughput by structuring your application better(have more no. of peers etc). Yes, there'll be a limit to how many transactions you can do per second even when you have a good architecture, but isn't it what blockchain infamous for?

There're other ways of increasing the throughput depending on the use-case. One could be returning the response to the API caller as soon as the transaction gets endorsed, not waiting for the transaction to get committed in the ledger. There're definitely some cons to this approach like getting an MVCC error later but if handled properly, this can be one of the best ways to increase the throughput in Hyperledger Fabric.

> The documents that assessors want to record after completing their work may include images, videos, and a lot of information. How should this information be stored on the network? Doesn't it create a heavy load on the network?

There's no need of storing blob files in the database. It doesn't have anything to do with blockchain. In a simple project which handles uploading and downloading images/videos, you don't save those files in your database. You just store the name in the database which points to a file in the filesystem.

You can read more about "Should you store images in DB or not?" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).